# Model Post with different types in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question on how to build the models in Rails. Let's for example take the social network tumblr. You can post there in different ways. Links, just text, photos, conversations. Now I would like to do something similar, but I am kind of stock with the modeling of my app. Let's say I want to have a `Post` model. So my users can post either just a text or one with an image. So i guess I need an `Image` model too. Let's say I want that my users can post an event but as a form of a post. So i guess I need a `Event` model. And so on, maybe in future I will have another idea for another type of post (so it should be always releated to the post). How would you build the models and the relations so it is easily expandable? I am thinking of something like **Enums** from Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use one model `Post` for all post's types(image,event...)
For example `posts` table:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.belongs_to :author
  t.column :post_type, :integer, default: 0
  t.column :title, :string
  t.column :body, :text
  t.column :image_url, :string
  t.column :star_at, :datetime
  t.column :end_at, :datetime
  t.timestamps
end
```

Model will have specific validation for each post type:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum post_type: [ :event, :image, :message] 

  validates :image_url, presence: true, if: ->{ image? }
  validates :start_at, :end_at, presence: true, if: ->{ event? }
  validates :title, :body, presence: true, if: ->{ message? }
end
```

Reasons to choose this way:

- Easy fetch all data from database. No unions, no multiple selects.
- Easy manage caching, owner's rules, ...
- Use model's concerns for every post type to have a clean model.

Comment: Okay, can you explain me why it should be better use just one model for all types instead of using multiple models?

Comment: added reasons to the answer